# TabBarController for music program

Tags: ios, swift, uitabbarcontroller, tabbar, uitabbaritem

I use `tabBarController` to create a music program and I have questions like how to do it as shown in gif

**Questions:**

1. How to do so that when you click on tabBarItem, "`presentViewController`" worked
2. How to make it so that the photo does not change color and make it round, only in the third `tabBarItem`

   Preferably without libraries

[image]

it should be

[image]

**My TabBarController**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
     super.viewDidLoad()

    self.delegate = self
    
    // меняет цвет фона tabBar
    self.tabBar.barTintColor = .white
    
    // меняет цвет UITabBarItem and Title
    UITabBar.appearance().tintColor = UIColor(hex: 0x0077fe, alpha: 1)
    
    //меняет цвет background UITabBar
    UITabBar.appearance().barTintColor = UIColor.white
    
    
    // делает фон серым
    for item in self.tabBar.items! {
        if let image = item.image {
            item.image = image.withRenderingMode(.alwaysOriginal)

        }
    }
    
    //показывает и переходит в контроллеры
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let controller1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main") as! VCMain
    let controller2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "search")
    let controller3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player")
    let controller4 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bookmark")
    let controller5 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menu")
    
    self.setViewControllers([controller1,controller2,controller3,controller4,controller5], animated: true)
    
    // создает навигационный контроллер для контроллеров
    let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller1)
    let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller2)
    let vc3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller3)
    let vc4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller4)
    let vc5 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller5)
    
    viewControllers = [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5]
    
}

override func tabBar(_ tabBar: UITabBar, didSelect item: UITabBarItem) {
    
    print(item.tag)
    if item.tag == 0{
        if GlobalModals.count != 0 {
            let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
            let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as? VCPlayer
            self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
        }
    }
}
```

**Player**

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
  
        let im = Extension.resizeImage(image:GlobalModals[thisSong].ImageView! , targetSize: CGSize.init(width:20, height: 20))
        self.tabBarController?.tabBar.items![2].image = im
    }
 }
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I created a view and a button on it in tabBarController and created a func that sets the parameters and call it after I set all the view controllers also created a notificationCenter that could change the button image from another controller

```
class TabBarController: UITabBarController,UITabBarControllerDelegate {


open var playerBtn = UIButton()

//func for NotificationCenter
@objc func imageChange() {
    if GlobalModals.count != 0 {
        playerBtn.setImage(GlobalModals[thisSong].ImageView, for: .normal)
    }
}

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()

    NotificationCenter.default.addObserver(self, selector: #selector(imageChange), name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "imageChange"), object: nil)

    self.delegate = self

    //shows and goes to controllers
    let storyBoard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle:nil)
    let controller1 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "main") as! VCMain
    let controller2 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "search")
    let controller3 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player")
    let controller4 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "bookmark")
    let controller5 = storyBoard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "menu")

    self.setViewControllers([controller1,controller2,controller4,controller5], animated: true)

    // creates navigation controller
    let vc1 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller1)
    let vc2 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller2)
    let vc3 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller3)
    let vc4 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller4)
    let vc5 = UINavigationController(rootViewController: controller5)

    viewControllers = [vc1, vc2, vc3, vc4, vc5]

    self.setupMiddleButton()



}

// TabBarButton – Setup Middle Button and View
func setupMiddleButton() {
    playerBtn.frame = CGRect(x: 0, y: 0, width: 45, height: 45)
    var playerBtnFrame = playerBtn.frame
    playerBtnFrame.origin.y = self.view.bounds.height - playerBtnFrame.height - 2
    playerBtnFrame.origin.x = self.view.bounds.width / 2 - playerBtnFrame.size.width / 2
    playerBtn.frame = playerBtnFrame
    playerBtn.layer.cornerRadius = playerBtnFrame.height/2
    playerBtn.layer.masksToBounds = true
    playerBtn.contentMode = .scaleAspectFill


    let view = UIView()
    let width = self.view.frame.width/5
    let xWidth = width*2
    view.frame = CGRect(x:  xWidth , y: playerBtnFrame.origin.y - 2, width: self.view.frame.width/5, height: tabBar.frame.height)
    view.backgroundColor = .clear
    self.view.addSubview(view)
    self.view.addSubview(playerBtn)

    playerBtn.setImage(UIImage(named: "home"), for: UIControlState.normal)
    playerBtn.addTarget(self, action: #selector(playerButtonAction), for: UIControlEvents.touchUpInside)

    self.view.layoutIfNeeded()
}

// Button Touch Action
@objc func playerButtonAction(sender: UIButton) {
    if GlobalModals.count != 0  {
        let storyboard = UIStoryboard(name: "Main", bundle: nil)
        let vc = storyboard.instantiateViewController(withIdentifier: "player") as? VCPlayer
        self.present(vc!, animated: true, completion: nil)
    }
}

}
```

so I change the image of the button

```
    NotificationCenter.default.post(name: NSNotification.Name(rawValue: "imageChange"), object: nil)
```

Answer (score 1):

The TabBarController doesn't have those option, you need to implement it by subclassing.

You can use this library [Animated Tab Bar](https://github.com/Ramotion/animated-tab-bar) to achieve the same result with animation.

Comment: I do not want animation icons